# Call function after View is displayed

Tags: c++, mfc

I need to call a function right after the view is displayed. So, everytime I start the program or everytime I create or open a document. I searched but didnt find anything. Is there any function that does this? It must be something like `CView::OnInitialUpdate()`. Im working with C++ MFC.

Thank you

Comment: Post user-defined message from OnInitialUpdate and call the function from this message handler. Alternatively, start timer with some short interval, call the function from the timer handler and kill the timer.

Comment: Is this an SDI or an MDI application?

Comment: Why is OnInitialUpdate not a good place to place your Action?

Comment: It has to load a function which has a pointer to the doc in it. The program crashes when I'm working with OnInitialUpdate or OnUpdate. Its a MDI application.

Comment: "The program crashes" is a poor description of the problem. Is it an exception, a segfault...? Anyway, in OnInitialUpdate you should already have access to the document, which should already be properly created. You should show your code; otherwise it's very difficult to diagnose your problem.